# My local storage object keeps getting replaced instead of updated

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to update my local storage but somehow instead of getting updated the array is constantly being replaced. Could anyone help me? This is my code.

```
function saveRun(){
    runName = prompt("Please give a name for this run","");
    runInstance.setRunName(runName);
    savedRuns.push(runInstance);
    console.log("Run instance : " + runInstance);
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
        //Stringify runInstance to a JSON string
        if (typeof localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== null) {
            //Retrieve the stored JSON string
            let retrievedRun = localStorage.getItem(runKey);
            //Parse into a new variable
            let runObject = JSON.parse(retrievedRun);
            //Convert object into a JSON string
            let stringifiedRun = JSON.stringify(savedRuns);
            //Store this JSON string to local storage using the runKey
            localStorage.setItem(runKey,stringifiedRun);
            //console.log("Saved runs: " + savedRuns)

        } else {
            //Convert object into a JSON string
            let stringifiedRun = JSON.stringify(savedRuns);
            //Store this JSON string to local storage using the runKey
            localStorage.setItem(runKey,stringifiedRun);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error: localStorage is not supported by current browser.");
    }

    //Now clear memory.
    runInstance = null;

}
```

Comment: What is `runKey` here? Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: `typeof localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== null` will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: ^^ you either want to remove `typeof` (`localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== null`) or change `null` to `"null"` (`typeof localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== "null"`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code retrieves `retrievedRun` and parses it into `runObject` and then completely ignores that and instead goes on to stringifying `savedRuns` and saving that. So yes, it gets completely replaced. If you wanted to *update* it, you'd modify `runObject` and then stringify and save that, rather than saving something else entirely (`savedRuns`/`stringifiedRun`).

As separate issue is that, as CertainPerformance points out in a comment, `typeof localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== null` will always be true. You either want to remove `typeof` (`localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== null`) or change `null` to `"null"` (`typeof localStorage.getItem("savedRuns") !== "null"`).